# wordpress media filter on image modal

Tags: wordpress

on wordpress when i use the image block and open the media modal to upload or select a media, in the Media Library tab i only see the filter by months.

ON the next image i show the filter i want to include on the select image modal.

[image: i want to add a new filter on the select image modal]

Some of the media image is marked as Favorite using the meta_key _favorite=1.

I want to add a filter that can work on the image select modal to filter only the images marked as Favorite.

When i add the Favorite filter on the media modal i use the next code, but this not works on the select media modal because i only see the months filter:

```
add_filter('media_view_settings', 'favorite_image_filter', 999);

function favorite_image_filter($settings) {
    $settings['mimeTypes']['favoritesimages'] = 'Favorites';
    return $settings;
}
```

Thanks for your help